# Ant Design table delete and edit functionalities not reflecting on the PG database

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I am trying to implement crud functionalities in Ant design table. I observed that the delete and edit functionalities only works on the instance when I perform the operations on initial render, but after reloading the component, the table returns back to its initial state and the operations don't affect the database in any way.

I see this error on my console

```
     Type '{ title: string; dataIndex: string; key: string; align: string; editable: boolean; 
     render?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'ColumnType<any>'.
     Types of property 'align' are incompatible.
     Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'AlignType'.
```

These are the codes below, I hope to break them down in code blocks so they can be understandable

imports

```
   import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
   import { Table, Popconfirm, Button, Space, Input, Form } from 'antd';   
   import { isEmpty } from 'lodash';
```

api

```
    const apiUrl = 'api/terminals';
```

useState and useEffect codes

```
    const [gridData, setGridData] = useState([]);
    const [loader, setLoader] = useState(false);
    const [editingKey, setEditingKey] = useState('');
    const [editRow, setEditRow] = useState(false);
    const [form] = Form.useForm();

    useEffect(() => {
    loadData();
     }, []);

   const loadData = async () => {
   setLoader(true);
   const response = await axios.get(apiUrl);
   setGridData(response.data);
   setLoader(false);
     };
```

modifiedData codes

```
     const modifiedData = gridData.map(({ ...item }) => ({
     ...item,
     key: item.id,
     }));
    const save = async key => {
    try {
    const row = await form.validateFields();
    const newData = [...modifiedData];
    const index = newData.findIndex(item => key === item.key);
    if (index > -1) {
    const item = newData[index];
    newData.splice(index, 1, { ...item, ...row });
    setGridData(newData);
    setEditingKey('');
     }
    } catch (error) {
    console.warn('Error', error);
    }
    };
```

edit and cancel function code block

```
       const edit = record => {
       form.setFieldsValue({
       name: '',
       stock: '',
       stockLevelDate: '',
       tankThreatLevel: '',
       tankThreatLevelColor: '',
       tankTopPosition: '',
       tankTopPositionColor: '',
       lowPumpable: '',
       lowPumpableColor: '',
       tankCapacity: '',
       ...record,
       });
       setEditingKey(record.key);
       };
      const cancel = () => {
      setEditingKey('');
      };
```

editableCell function block

```
      const EditableCell = ({ editing, dataIndex, title, record, children, ...restProps }) => 
    {
     const input = <Input />;
     return (
     <td {...restProps}>
      {editing ? (
      <Form.Item
        name={dataIndex}
        style={{ margin: 0 }}
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: `Please input ${title}`,
          },
        ]}
        >
        {input}
       </Form.Item>
       ) : (
      children
      )}
      </td>
      );
      };
```

editing code block

```
      const isEditing = record => {
     return record.key === editingKey;
     };
```

columns block

```
       const columns = [
        {
       title: 'ID',
       dataIndex: 'id',
       key: 'id',
        },
       {
      title: 'Name' as string,
      dataIndex: 'name',
      key: 'name',
      align: 'center',
      editable: true,
      },
      {
     title: 'Stock',
     dataIndex: 'stock',
      key: 'stock',
     align: 'center',
      editable: true,
      },
     {
     title: 'Stock Level Date',
     dataIndex: 'stockLevelDate',
      key: 'stockLevelDate',
      align: 'center',
      editable: true,
     },
    {
    title: 'Tank Threat Level',
    dataIndex: 'tankThreatLevel',
    key: 'tankThreatLevel',
    align: 'center',
    editable: true,
    },
    {
    title: 'Tank Threat Level Color',
    dataIndex: 'tankThreatLevelColor',
    key: 'tankThreatLevelColor',
    align: 'center',
    editable: true,
    },
    {
    title: 'Tank Top Position',
    dataIndex: 'tankTopPosition',
    key: 'tankTopPosition',
    align: 'center',
    editable: true,
    },
    {
    title: 'Tank Top Position Color',
    dataIndex: 'tankTopPositionColor',
    key: 'tankTopPositionColor',
    align: 'center',
    editable: true,
    },
    {
    title: 'Low Pumpable',
    dataIndex: 'lowPumpable',
    key: 'lowPumpable',
    align: 'center',
    editable: true,
    },
    {
    title: 'Low Pumpable Color',
    dataIndex: 'lowPumpableColor',
    key: 'lowPumpableColor',
    align: 'center',
    editable: true,
    },
     {
    title: 'Tank Capacity',
    dataIndex: 'tankCapacity',
    key: 'tankCapacity',
    align: 'center',
    editable: true,
    },
     {
     title: 'Actions',
     dataIndex: 'actions',
     key: 'actions',
     align: 'center',
     render: (_, record) => {
     const editable = isEditing(record);
     return modifiedData.length >= 1 ? (
      <Space>
        <Popconfirm title="Sure to delete?" onConfirm={() => handleDelete(record)}>
          <Button type="primary" disabled={editable} danger>
            Delete
          </Button>
        </Popconfirm>
        {editable ? (
          <span>
            <Space size="middle">
              <Button onClick={e => save(record.key)} type="primary" style={{ marginRight: 8 
               }}>
                {' '}
                Save
              </Button>
              <Popconfirm title="Sure to cancel?" onConfirm={cancel}>
                <Button>Cancel</Button>
              </Popconfirm>
            </Space>
          </span>
         ) : (
          <Button onClick={() => edit(record)} type="primary">
            Edit
          </Button>
         )}
        </Space>
        ) : null;
         },
         },
         ];
```

mergedCoulumns block

```
       const mergedColumns = columns.map(col => {
      if (!col.editable) {
       return col;
        }
       return {
       ...col,
       onCell: record => ({
       record,
       dataIndex: col.dataIndex,
       title: col.title,
       editing: isEditing(record),
       }),
       };
       });
```

handleDelete code block

```
         const handleDelete = value => {
     const dataSource = [...modifiedData];
      const filteredData = dataSource.filter(item => item.id !== value.id);
     setGridData(filteredData);
      };
```

return jsx

```
      <>
      <div>
      <h2>Terminals</h2>
      <Link to={`${match.url}/new`} className="btn btn-primary jh-create-entity" id="jh       
     -create- 
     entity" data-cy="entityCreateButton">
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon="plus" />
      &nbsp; Add Terminal
     </Link>

      <hr color="red" />
      <Form form={form} component={false}>
        <Table
        components={{
          body: {
            cell: EditableCell,
          },
        }}
        columns={mergedColumns}
        dataSource={modifiedData}
        bordered
        loading={loader}
       />
        </Form>
       </div>
      </>
```

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Your custom frontend code does not compile. This is not a JHipster issue and has nothing to do with PgAdmin. Please fix your question tags.

Comment: Pls what do you mean by my frontend codes does not compile

Comment: The errors you pasted from your console are from typescript compiler: "Type 'xxx' is not assignable to type 'yyy'". Try a prod build and you'll see.

Comment: Pls what do you mean by "prod build". Is it why the crud operations have no effect on my database

Comment: Read the docs or your project's README and/or package.json for prod build, it's basically a stricter build that is used for deployment not dev. Having compilation errors could mean that you're using an old version of your frontend not the latest changes. Then, if this does not help, you should have a look at backend logs, especially when enabling transaction debug level.

Comment: Thank you sir. You are right, I am going to meet with the backend dev for the code review and debugging. I appreciate